# Which language format to choose for GCP "Logging query language" in the Code Blocks Extension of Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, google-docs-addon

Which language format should I choose in the Google Docs Extension "Code Blocks"

[image]

to get the
[Logging query language](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logging-query-language)

> The Logging query language syntax can be thought of in terms of queries and comparisons.
> A query is a string containing an expression

that is used in the Query window of GCP logs?

[image]

With the example:

> "String1"
> AND "String2"

that shall get the same colour ranges as in the GCP query editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through most of the items that caught my eyes, and the most suitable seems to be *php* language since it marks the booleans and strings in a way how you see it in the GCP query editor.

php/auto:
[image]

swift:
[image]

Though swift could get a try if you like another colour setting, php is more likely the default that should be taken since it is the same as choosing "auto", and it "php" is just a classic.